# Change post title after post thumbnail set

Tags: wordpress

In my case I want to automatically change post title after setting post thumbnail - the title of post should be the same as image name. As I can see in console admin-ajax.php response the **data** value where the name of image is, but I completly don't konow how to pass this value to my jquery code (I want to use this feature in my plugin).

Is it possible to pass response from admin-ajax.php after setting post thumbnail to my jquery code, or maybe there is hook which can load my registered script after setting post thumbnail?

Any ideas/answers will be appreciated ;)

Comment: if the title is fixed,that we are going to st..then we can change...

Comment: yes it is ok, title should be copied from image title to post title - automatically after set post thumbnail

Comment: we can't change permanant, but we could display that...

Comment: hmm... how we can make it? I dont have any idea how to make it

Comment: you can apply j query over backend.. but may be quite confuse, is there any other alternative..?

Comment: i can reqister script and equeue it (code will be used as plugin), but there still question: how to pass data from admin-ajax.php (response after setting post thumbnail) to my plugin script?